# Teamcity email only 10 changes are shown, how to show more changes

Tags: teamcity

The Teamcity notification email after build successful only show 10 changes. I want to know how to config in teamcity to show more changes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can create the `internal.properties` in config folder, and included following properties,

`teamcity.notification.template.update.interval` - how often the templates are reread by system (integer, in seconds, default 60)

`teamcity.notification.includeDebugInfo` - include debug information into the message in case of template processing errors (boolean, default false)

`teamcity.notification.maxChangesNum` - max number of changes to list in e-mail message (integer, default 10)

`teamcity.notification.maxCompilationDataSize` - max size (in bytes) of compilation error data to include in e-mail message (integer, default 20480)

`teamcity.notification.maxFailedTestNum` - max number of failed tests to list in e-mail message (integer, default 50)

`teamcity.notification.maxFailedTestStacktraces` - max number of test stacktraces in e-mail message (integer, default 5)

`teamcity.notification.maxFailedTestDataSize` - max size (in bytes) of failed test output data to include in a single e-mail message (integer, default 10240)

more details see, https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+TeamCity+Server+Startup+Properties

Answer (score 0):

Imho, it seems TC does not clearly support anything away from out of the box defaults. In other words, lots of things are apparently configurable but there is no documentation nor will a query to their board receive a reply. Instead, the solution seems to be to assume that all the template files can be edited pretty much at will to provide the desired results.

This issue is a case in point. One user gave a generic answer to how to find/edit the notification template in general; 
http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/293800
TeamCity 5.1 Email template :: JetBrains Developer Community
devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/293800Feb 7, 2011 – I'm going to begin use TeamCity for our projects. ... getViewChangesUrl(bean.build)}'>${modNum} change<@plural modNum/> ...

Note that he cites the "modNum" value, which is our problematic item. Its default appears to be 10 per out-of-the-box settings. (I don't think we can see that part.) I was able to easily change it by assigning a new value.

In my file [ServerConfigsPath]\config_notifications\email\common.ftl , I now have;

```
<!-- was  #assign modNum=bean.modificationsNumber/ -->
```

<#assign modNum=100/>

I hope this helps you or another newbie. I love SO!
//sorry for spacing on the code, I can't see how to get it right...